# Is there a way to delete maven launch configurations in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I ran different builds in Eclipse, but I don't need them anymore. Is there a way to delete them.
The launch configurations can be seen in the GIF image below:
[image]

I would like to delete them both.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this done theough right clicking on the project file -> hovering ove 'Run As' -> then selecting the 'run configurations' option. The saved launch configurations can then be seen on the side.[image]

Right click on the launch configuration then choose the delete option.